# Group by a Substring mysql not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, substring

I want to use GROUP BY clause on a query in case IFF it's column TYPE contains [Sale], for that purpose I put the query below,

```
SELECT 
   PAYABLE_TYPE AS TYPE,
   CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(PAYABLE_TYPE, 1,6) = '[Sale]') THEN PAYABLE_TYPE END AS T,
   PAYABLE_PARTICULAR AS PARTICULAR,
   DEBIT,
   CREDIT,
   PAYABLE_DATE AS DATE
FROM PAYABLES
WHERE PAYABLE_DATE >= $P{DateStart} && PAYABLE_DATE <= $P{DateEnd}
GROUP BY T
```

But it only returns me 2 lines at all, what I have is in the image below and the GREEN boxed line shows what I need to group. One more thing I need that grouped total to be sum up as well there. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What are the results that you want?  The query is working correctly, returning two rows with `type` being '[Sales]' and `NULL`.

Comment: I need to group by on the value [Sale] from column TYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by the sales but leave the other rows intact.  Let me assume that you have a unique `id` on each row that is a non-negative integer:

```
SELECT 
   PAYABLE_TYPE AS TYPE,
   CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(PAYABLE_TYPE, 1,6) = '[Sale]') THEN PAYABLE_TYPE END AS T,
   max(PAYABLE_PARTICULAR) AS PARTICULAR,
   sum(DEBIT) as debit,
   sum(CREDIT) as credit,
   PAYABLE_DATE AS DATE
FROM PAYABLES
WHERE PAYABLE_DATE >= $P{DateStart} && PAYABLE_DATE <= $P{DateEnd}
GROUP BY PAYABLE_DATE, (case WHEN (SUBSTRING(PAYABLE_TYPE, 1,6) = '[Sale]') then -1 else id end);
```

Comment: But that giving just one line for SALE in whole, I need to have it differently on different date ranges, like if SALE only done for 19th Sep. Then other things like Stock In and then again on 23rd Sep SALE again....

Comment: I added the payable_date into the `group by`, which should solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks man, It was showing 2 rows for even a SEC difference in date, but I did that with date format thing. Thanks! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You have no aggregate functions in the query. Maybe you are trying to do something like this?

```
SELECT TYPE, T, PARTICULAR, DATE, SUM(DEBIT), SUM(CREDIT) FROM
(SELECT 
   PAYABLE_TYPE AS TYPE,
   CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(PAYABLE_TYPE, 1,6) = '[Sale]') THEN PAYABLE_TYPE END AS T,
   PAYABLE_PARTICULAR AS PARTICULAR,
   DEBIT,
   CREDIT,
   PAYABLE_DATE AS DATE
FROM PAYABLES
WHERE PAYABLE_DATE >= $P{DateStart} && PAYABLE_DATE <= $P{DateEnd})
GROUP BY TYPE, T, PARTICULAR, DATE
```

Comment: MySQL supports the use of column aliases in the `group by` clause (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html).

Comment: Got it. I'm mainly an Oracle person.